# Gitbash me da error al hacer un push a mi Github remoto

Tags: git, github, ssl, git-push, push

El error aparece según la siguiente imagen :

[image: imagen de error]

Comment: El mismo mensaje te lo dice, estás intentando subir cambios y en tu remoto tienes cambios que no tienes en tu local, lo que tienes que hacer es un git pull esto bajará los cambios del remoto a tu local y a continuación has el push

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que estás intentando subir cambios al remoto y tu local no tiene todos los cambios que existen en remoto.

Lo que tienes que hacer es un:
`git pull` esto bajará los cambios del remoto a tu local.
Luego:
`git push` esto subirá ya los cambios.

prueba mirar esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-remote) al mismo error, es un poco antigua pero la solución es la misma.

Answer (score 0):

@cristhian ocaña eso es porque tienes cambios en el servidor. Ami me acaba de pasar hace poco. Lo he solucionando haciendo un **pull** de la rama donde quiero subir. Despues hago otro **pull** de la otra rama donde estoy trabajando y despues realizo el **push**

Piensa que yo tengo lo siguiente:

- Una rama donde trabajo
- Otra rama donde trabaja un compañero
- La ramma Dev donde lo unimos
- 

En Dev es donde hay los problemas haveces porque quieres subir y hay cambios, por lo tanto hago un pull despues un push de mi rama, despues hago un pull de dev despues un pull de mi ramma y despues el push.

espero que se entienda...